# React Native gradlew bundleRelease and run-android --variant=release make different APKs

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, google-play

I'm trying to release a React Native (v0.61.5) app on the Google Play Store but the App Bundle format doesn't create the correct APK (tried on a OnePlus 6t, Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 and the Android emulator Pixel 3 API 29 (Google APIs) x86_64)

I do have Android flavors setup as follows:

```
flavorDimensions "server"
productFlavors {
    local {
        dimension "server"
        applicationIdSuffix ".local"
        versionNameSuffix "-local"
    }
    staging {
        dimension "server"
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        versionNameSuffix "-staging"
    }
    production {
        dimension "server"
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

When I launch the app with run-android works as it should:

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=productionRelease
```

But if I try to make the .aab the app runs but on the first boot loads 20~ MB on the user data and when running the app it has random behaviors, lags and freezes and I can't identify what can it be:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew bundleProductionRelease
```

On android/build.gradle I have the following:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3')
        // FIREBASE
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    if (names.contains("reactNative51") || names.contains("reactNative55")) {
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using gradle 5.5:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip
```

On gradle.properties I have enabled AndroidX and Jetifier:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

On android/app/build.gradle I did change also:

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    bundleInRelease: false,
]

buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        shrinkResources true
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false
        pseudoLocalesEnabled false
        zipAlignEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Because of `bundleInRelease: false` I make the bundle before calling Gradle with:

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

I test the *.aab* with *bundletool* with:

```
java -jar ./bundletool-all-0.13.0.jar build-apks --bundle=./app-production-release.aab  --output=./release.apks --ks=./myapp-upload-key.keystore --ks-pass=pass:mypassword --ks-key-alias=myapp-key-alias --key-pass=pass:mypassword
```

And then I install the APK to the device:

```
java -jar ./bundletool-all-0.13.0.jar install-apks --apks=./release.apks
```

Before launch

[image: before launch]

After first launch (without doing anything else other than running the app)

[image: after first launch]

This happens only with the App Bundle, is it possible that the *bundletool* is missing some pieces or is the *.aab* that generated wrongly?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Using async storage to store a boolean and the user data in app storage is around 18MB! Surely, something is not right.

Comment: @AbdulSadikYalcin I had an issue open on GitHub, if you can try and tell me because I think is not async storage https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28220

Comment: Your issue is locked; cannot write on there anymore. I don't know the reason; looking for a solution like you.